# Safety and stability of SetParent() and GetParent()

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

I'm using the following functions in my program:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);
```

My question is: is this approach safe and stable? My development machine is Windows XP and so far I didn't find any problem with its use. I wonder if I can have issues in different versions (e.g. Windows Vista, Windows 7, whatever), different cpus (x64), etc. Can you guys provide some feedback on this and if there are some potencial issues how can I overcome them?

Thanks in advance.

Zubrowka

Comment: SetParent is a pretty icky function, it gets abused a lot to glue windows together that belong to different threads or processes.  Which has a knack for turning a process catatonic when the glued one stops responding to messages.  Thread safety gets murky too.  Whether that's relevant to you is impossible to guess from the question.  You have little to fear from Windows versions, keeping the winapi stable is Microsoft's bread and butter.

Comment: Nice one Hans, thanks. I'm going to make a short code review concerning the points that you mentioned!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those P/invoke declarations are correct for all versions of Windows. No problems with XP/Vista/7 and no 32/64 bit issues. `IntPtr` floats between 32 and 64 bit depending on the bitness of the process. That's exactly what you need to happen for an `HWND`.

Comment: +1 for IntPtr floats between 32 and 64 bit depending on the bitness of the process :)